# Error importing middleware cms.middleware.multilingual: "No module named multilingual"

Tags: django-cms, django-multilingual

Whenever i runserver and go the admin page in my browser i get:

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

and in Titanium Studio i see:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
>       self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 72, in **call**
>       return self.application(environ, start_response)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 236, in **call**
>       self.load_middleware()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 53, in load_middleware
>       raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
>   ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware cms.middleware.multilingual: "No module named multilingual"
>   [03/May/2013 12:42:06] "GET /favicon.ico/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59

I have installed multilingual and have `django_multilingual-0.1.0-py2.7.egg` in my site-packages folder.

If i print sys.path I have `C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_multilingual-0.1.0-py2.7.egg` in it.

I have `cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware` in my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on you Django-cms version you may be approaching it the wrong way. They changed how internationalization is done in 2.4. Have a look at [this page](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.0/advanced/i18n.html). This is the newest method.

What you are attempting is from earlier versions, like [this page](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.3.6/advanced/i18n.html), and that may be correct as long as your version is not the latest.

Comment: Many thanks, you were right. I was trying to do internationalization from CMS 2.3 with the latest version of CMS and it didn't like it

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Django-CMS 2.3 to 2.4 upgrade section](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.3/upgrade/2.4.html#removed-the-multilingualmiddleware) for Multilingual URLs.